# How to prove every holomorphic vector bundle on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is an algebraic vector bundle

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

It is well-known that every holomorphic vector bundle on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is an algebraic vector bundle, as a part of GAGA principle.

Where can I find a reference for a detailed proof of the above fact?

Comment: Serre's GAGA paper is available on the internet: http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1956__6__1_0/

Comment: @KReiser Which section of the GAGA paper is on the essential surjectivity of the analytification functor?

Comment: Subsection 12 contains the statement and subsections 15/16/17 contain the proof. If you skim the section titles and/or theorems and run them through google translate, it should be not so hard to find what you're looking for in most math written in French.